# Get instance of drop target object

Tags: javafx, drag-and-drop, droptarget

I need to have the instance of the object on which the user dragged something. I'm looking at `event.getTarget()`, but I'm still not able to get the actual object.
Here is what I have now:

```
scrollPane.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {

    private Node hoveredNode;

    @Override
    public void handle(DragEvent event) {
        double windowHeight = scrollPane.getHeight();
        if(!event.getTarget().getClass().getName().contains("FlowPane"))
            logger.severe(event.getTarget().getClass().getName() + "");
        double topBar = (20*windowHeight)/100;
        double bottomBar = windowHeight - topBar;
        event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.LINK);
        if(event.getY() > 0 && event.getY() < topBar && scrollPane.getVvalue() > 0) {
        scrollPane.setVvalue(scrollPane.getVvalue()-0.001);
        }
        else if(event.getY() < windowHeight && event.getY() > bottomBar && scrollPane.getVvalue() < 1){
            scrollPane.setVvalue(scrollPane.getVvalue()+0.001);
        }
    }
});
```

Now I'm just logging the target class name if it's not a FlowPane. I need to have the instance of the actual object, because I want to apply the hover effect on it.

Can you suggest me something to work on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `event.getTarget()` or `event.getSource()`, as you already do, but you have to cast the object you retrieve to a specific class. Then you can modify it.

For a reference, take a look at the following SSCCE.

```
public class JavaFXTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();     

        Text text = new Text("Test");
        text.setOnDragDetected((Event event) -> {
            ((Text)event.getSource()).setStyle("-fx-stroke: red;");
            event.consume();
        });
        root.getChildren().add(text);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Nothing fancy, once you start trying to drag the text it will turn red.

Comment: Thank you. Now I'm able to get the actual instance.